# Dim/Dark Screen on Acer Aspire

Tags: 11.10, laptop, wubi, screen

I do have WUBI on my desktop, but that computer is too laggy so I installed WUBI on my Acer Aspire laptop. Everything works fine except the screen is too dark. I tried to reinstall  WUBI but nothing. I need to use the flash-light to see what is on the screen. I tried a program called "brightness indicator" . I tried with `sudo apt-get install acpi`, but nothing. I updated all my packages and still nothing. Please some help will be appreciated.

Note: Do not ask me about graphics card, i do not know anything about it >_<

Comment: Please Post the output of `lspci|grep VGA`

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864513

Comment: Also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/826386

Answer (score 1):

Try system settings -> screen (has a lock symbol) -> uncheck "Dim to save power"

Answer (score 0):

Well I assume you are using a laptop having backlight issue in ubuntu, probably emachines(old acer) laptops shows off. I recommend you to create file and add contents as follows.

1. Become Root .

> ```
> sudo -i
> ```

2. Create a new file

> ```
> gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
> ```

3. Enter the following contents in it.

> #!/bin/sh
>
> #run 'setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00' when waking up
>
> ```
> case "$1" in
>         thaw|resume)
>            setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00
>             ;;
> esac
> ```

4. Save the file.
5. Make it executable

> ```
> sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/99_backlight
> ```

6. Reboot your system.

> ```
> sudo reboot
> ```